# Handlebar custom helper stuck on "doesn't match each"

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to make certain elements lowercase by using handlebars (I know it's possible with CSS, but you can't do that for classnames for example). Anyhow, I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: toLowerCase doesn't match each
```

My code:

```
    <script id="icon-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each results}}
        <li>
            <div class="content">
                    <i class="Icon icon-{{#toLowerCase contentType}}"></i>
            </div>
       </li>
       {{/each}}
    </script>
```

Custom helper:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Handlebars.registerHelper("toLowerCase", function(input) {
    var output = input.toLowerCase();
    return output.replace(" ", "");
});
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't close your `div` tag. :)

Comment: Thanks, changed that. It was in the code, missed it here though. Problem still remains.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured it out. For anyone having the same problems:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
handlebars.registerHelper("toLowerCase", function(input) {
    var output = input.toLowerCase();
    return output.replace(" ", "");
});
</script>
```

**Handlebars** must have a lowercase letter (like this: `handlebars`) at first & no hashtag is needed when you are using a custom helper. So the custom helper is now `toLowerCase` instead of `#toLowerCase`

```
<script id="icon-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each results}}
    <li>
        <div class="content">
                <i class="Icon icon-{{toLowerCase contentType}}"></i>
        </div>
   </li>
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: not sure why it got downvoted; this helped me, thanks!

Comment: Where are the docs to support this? I understand the problem to be function vs block expression. Only block expressions are used with a `#` before their name.

Answer (score 16):

If a handlebars helper name is all lowercase:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
handlebars.registerHelper("lower", function(input) {
    var output = input.toLowerCase();
    return output.replace(" ", "");
});
</script>
```

you will need to use the hash when invoking it:

```
<script id="icon-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <i class="Icon icon-{{#lower contentType}}"></i>
</script>
```

If the helper uses a CamelCase name:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
handlebars.registerHelper("toLowerCase", function(input) {
    var output = input.toLowerCase();
    return output.replace(" ", "");
});
</script>
```

then you do not use the hash:

```
<script id="icon-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <i class="Icon icon-{{toLowerCase contentType}}"></i>
</script>
```

Comment: the answer from OP gives a solution, but this answer here actually gives also a better explanation

Answer (score 0):

It matters how you invoke the helper.  If you use a hash(#) then it's considered a [Block Helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) and needs to be closed.  Otherwise you'll get that parsing error.

```
{{#toLowerCase}}Some UPPERCASE text{{/toLowerCase}}
```

Obviously it also matters what the helper code does.  The syntax above is correct but the code may not have the desired effect.